# XSLT 1.0 parse/split delimited string with recursive template and check for exact value

Tags: arrays, string, split, xslt-1.0, csv

I'm trying to split a delimited string in XSLT 1.0 using a recursive template.

My string is dynamic, and it sometimes has a #^# delimiter and sometimes it doesn't. I want to check if the string contains an exact value of 'SMB30DAYSFREE' and print some text if it does. I can't use the contains operator because sometimes other values share the the same text. Example: 'INVSMB30DAYSFREE'.

A few examples of what the string could be:

- SMB30DAYSFREE#^#ENT30DAYSFREE#^#CLI60DAYSFREE
- INVSMB30DAYSFREE#^#ENT30DAYSFREE#^#CLI60DAYSFREE
- ENT30DAYSFREE#^#CLI60DAYSFREE#^#SMB30DAYSFREE
- SMB30DAYSFREE

Below is what I have so far but it isn't working. Any advice? Thanks!

```
<!--call the tokenizeString template-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="/transaction/data_xml/document/appliedPromotion_quote"/><!--delimited list of values--><!--delimited list of values-->
        <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'#^#'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
<xsl:/template>
<!--############################################################-->
<!--## Template to tokenize strings                           ##-->
<!--############################################################-->
<xsl:template name="tokenizeString">
    <!--passed template parameter -->
    <xsl:param name="list"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">                
            <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
            <xsl:variable name="promo" select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:if test="$promo = SMB30DAYSFREE">
                <fo:block>
                    SMB30DAYSFREE
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:if>
             <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose> 
                <xsl:when test="$list = ''">
                    <xsl:text/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:block>
                        SMB30DAYSFREE
                    </fo:block>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is rather confusing. It seems like you want to test if the string contains a **token** with the *exact* value of  `SMB30DAYSFREE`. If this is correct, you could make your test simply:

```
contains(concat('#^#', $string, '#^#'), '#^#SMB30DAYSFREE#^#')
```

and do away with the tokenizing.

Comment: Wow, it really is that simple. Thank you!